# Proving the following question: Z[3i] isn't PID by use of the quotient map Z/(3i) isn't a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, principal-ideal-domains

I was wondering if this methodology is sound. I've checked that for any element in $\mathbb{Z}[3i]$ if we take the quotient map with ideal $(3i)$, its kernel consists of the elements $ \{ 9a+3bi \}$. Since this essentially sends all of $(3i)$ and $9\mathbb{Z}$ to the 0 coset. I was wondering if this was in any way similar to the quotient map $\mathbb{Z} \, / \, 9\mathbb{Z} $. I realise that the elements of the cosets of $$\mathbb{Z}/(3i)=[x]=\{x: x+ (9a+3bi)\mathbb{Z}\}  $$  do not equal the cosets of $$\mathbb{Z} \, / \, 9\mathbb{Z}=[x]=\{x: x+ (9a+3bi)\mathbb{Z}\}  $$ but is there any way to relate these two to state they are equivilant, and therefore claim that since 3i is irreducible and prime, if $\mathbb{Z}/(3i)$ maps to domain that is equivalent to a domain that isn't a field, $\mathbb{Z}[3i]$ isn't a PID.

Comment: Honestly I do not understand what you are trying to do. Also, it is not really correctly written (for example (3i) is not an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$, nor is $[x]$ the same as the set of cosets, etc..).

Comment: just re-editing to clarify what I mean as its laid out a bit messily. Isn't (3i) an ideal in Z[3i] though? It contains 0, is closed under addition, and multiplication by any element of Z[3i]?

Comment: this is true, by definition you take the generated ideal $(3i)$ (in $\mathbb{Z}[3i]$) by the element $3i \in \mathbb{Z}[3i]$.

Comment: The problem is that $(3i)$ does not seem to be prime, as you have for example $9 \in (3i)$, right?

Comment: *But my comment also kind of already answers your question right?

Comment: I'm sort of asking whether I can claim Z[3i]/(3i) is isomorphic to Z/9Z since it sends (3i) and 9Z to 0. My reasoning sort of being the Z[x]/Z is isomorphic to Z since we can make a homomorphism that sends x to 0 leaving only Z left. However I might be fundamentally understanding quotient rings so I apologise if this isn't making much sense.

Comment: No, for any complex number $\alpha$, $\Bbb Z[\alpha]/(\alpha) \cong \Bbb Z$. You need to go back to basics. $9\in (3i)$, but so what? So is $6i$, for example.

Comment: Please make the bodies of your MSE questions self-contained and do not rely on the title for important information.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to show that $\mathbb{Z}[3i]$ is not a PID by showing that quotienting by a prime ideal does not give you field (since prime implies maximal in PID's). Please correct me if I am wrong in this assumption and edit your question to make it clearer what you are asking.

It is true that $\mathbb{Z}[3i]/(3i) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(9)$ but $(3i)$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[3i]$. Let's start with the first claim. Note that we have the following isomorphism.
$$\mathbb{Z}[3i] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+9).$$
The ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+9)$ that corresponds to the ideal $(3i)$ is $(x)$ so,
$$\mathbb{Z}[3i]/(3i) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+9,x).$$
Quoienting by $(x)$ first,
$$\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+9,x) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(0^2+9) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(9).$$
So yes, $\mathbb{Z}[3i]/(3i) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(9)$. Now for the other claim. The ring $\mathbb{Z}/(9)$ is not an integral domain since $3 \cdot 3 = 0$, so $(3i)$ can not be prime.

Comment: Thankyou! Yes that’s exactly what I wanted. Knew there was a method to my madness haha

Comment: @veganwithabeef Great, I’m glad!